# mb_convert_encoding issues

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have some issues with the PHP function mb_detect_encoding.
I can't convert it to ISO-8859-1. Any help?

**Code:**

```
$str = "åäö";
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($str);
echo $encoding;
            
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding(mb_convert_encoding($str, "ISO-8859-1"));
echo $encoding;
```

**Output:**

> UTF-8
>
> UTF-8

**Updated, solution:**

I updated mb_detect_order to array('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1') and it worked.

Comment: What is your `mb_detect_order()`?

Comment: Well there you go. I updated the mb_detect_order to UTF-8 in the beginning and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post it as an answer and accept it when you can.

Answer (score 9):

You've not actually converted your string.  Rather, the call to `mb_convert_encoding` did not assume that the original string was in UTF-8.  The string before the call was a byte sequence that could have been ISO-8859-1 already (and would have represented items differently).  You can see this is the case by, rather than calling the `mb_detect_encoding`, using `bin2hex` on the string and seeing the byte-sequence after the conversion call.  You'll see the byte sequence was unchanged.

To get the conversion to work, you need to tell it (in this case) the original encoding.  Use:

```
mb_convert_encoding($str, 'ISO-8859-1','utf-8');
```

If you examine the byte-sequence after this you'll see conversion has taken place.

Comment: Does ISO-8859-1 work for no-encoding "string"s (i.e. random invalid byte sequences)?

Answer (score -2):

I updated mb_detect_order to array('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1') and it worked

Comment: You are tricking yourself in to believing the conversion has worked.  Since c3a5c3a4c3b6 is a valid byte string in both UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 (representing different things in the two cases) you can get mb_detect_order to report it as either encoding.

Comment: @borrible What if his `mb_internal_encoding` has already been set to UTF-8?

Comment: @Passerby - It's not consistent with what we are seeing.  If the string had actually been converted to ISO-8859-1 it would have become the byte-sequence e5e4f6.  Now that's not valid UTF-8 so the mb_convert_encoding would not have reported UTF-8.  However, if the sequence had been left as c3a5c3a4c3b6 (valid UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1) we would get the situation described.

Comment: @borrible It is possible for `mb_detect_encoding` to always return "UTF-8" even the string is not valid UTF-8. My default `mb_detect_order` is `ASCII, UTF-8`. By only specifying `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8")`, and run OP's code plus `bin2hex` to debug, I can see the byte-sequence has been changed, but `mb_detect_encoding` will always return "UTF-8". PHP 5.3.10.

Comment: @Passerby - The net effect of your setting the mb_internal_encoding to UTF-8 is, in this case, equivalent to setting utf-8 as the third parameter to the mb_convert_encoding.  I think it unlikely, given that the OP does not talk about using other mb_ functions, that the situation he has seen means that the situation you describe has occurred.  I.e. I'd suggest it's more a potential solution to an incorrect conversion (although not the one I'd suggest) as opposed to the cause of his problem.

Comment: @borrible `mb_internal_encoding` can be _easily_ set in `php.ini`; Plus, you can do another experiment: leave `mb_internal_encoding` as default (ISO-8859-1 in my case), only use `mb_detect_order("UTF-8, ISO-8859-1")`(OP's solution), run OP's code (don't specify "from UTF-8"), and you will still get "UTF-8" instead of OP's new "ISO-8859-1" because the byte sequence is not changed.